# Critique: Icon design

Tags: icon, critique

I am producing a new application icon for a query menus and I would critique about this icon:

[image]

The aim of this icon is to represent the group of dishes, like in a folder tree found in many operating systems.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to GD.SE :) Please take a look at our [Critique Questions Guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). Why do you / don't you like your design? What are not sure about?

Comment: What do dishes have to do with it? Who's the audience? (Does 'query menus' mean it's a restaurant menu search tool?)

Comment: Yes, it's for a restaurant menu search tool, but it will be used by the kitchen staff to search for recipes.

Comment: How about a plate with a knife and fork, shaped and positioned like a search icon? (This is a comment because it's not a critique, but a suggestion instead.)

Comment: As an app icon, it likely should borrow heavily from (or be) the primary branding element. An app icon, like a logo, doesn't have to literally explain the app. It has to uniquely identify it. Does the app have a name yet? A brand identity? Or is the intention that this *is* the branding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a standard icon (read: thousands of apps use it) then it will be difficult to figure out no matter how well you design it. Add a label next to it, then the exact icon doesn't matter so much.

I'm yet to see a non-standard icon so incredibly clear that I immediately know what it means without labels.

Comment: Thanks for the support! I followed what you say and, finally, the icon looks better now.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the icon to include different types of dishes to better represent hierarchy.

For example on a traditional dinner setting. So maybe the top one is a dinner plate, then a saucer, then a cup, then a spoon.

Right now it just looks like a poorly aligned group of indiscriminate objects (I don't see them as plates).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to explain, I figure I'd post a visual suggestion, if the OP is stuck on using "dishes"/"Plates" as a icon theme. It kind of takes a riff of of what Ryan is promising with a stack of items - in this case "plates".

I hope this helps you!

Here it is:

[image]

Peace.

Comment: That looks a bit like the head of a guy with a mustache to me. "Push this button, get Pringles." http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/71/Pringles.svg/220px-Pringles.svg.png

Comment: I would love a push button to get Pringles!!!! MMMM! LOL

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the icon presented in the question. Some lines, circle, flying aliens?

I suggest not to use "folder"-like icon - no matter what you will do, it probably will be not original and not beautiful as you like.

IMHO you should find some "symbol" to your application and create just a beautiful icon even without any suggestion of menus/folder/archives etc.

IMHO [simple is better](http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=dish%20icon&search_group=&lang=en&language=en&search_source=search_form&version=llv1)